# Appium Server and WebDriver issue with Xcode

Tags: java, ios, iphone, safari, appium

The Appium Server logs says things like

> [XCUITest] Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of
> xcodebuild failure: Command 'carthage bootstrap --platform iOS,tvOS'
> exited with code 1

and

> Rebuild with --use-xcframeworks to create an xcframework bundle
> instead.

The error in IntelliJ is:

> unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
> Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild
> failure: Command 'carthage bootstrap --platform iOS,tvOS' exited with
> code 1 Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
> '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro', ip:
> '2601:c6:1:1380:0:0:0:e834%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
> 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_301' Driver info:
> driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

This is a simple test written by an Appium instructor on Linkedin Learning. I think some things may have changed since he uploaded the course.

Answer (score 0):

The possible cause for this issue could be a few Carthage libs installed on your mac.

You could try next:

```
npm uninstall carthage
brew uninstall carthage
brew install carthage

brew link --overwrite carthage
```